# Wiring Omron D6T Thermal Sensor to Raspberry Pi Zero W with Adafruit T-Cobbler Plus

Tags: ssh, hardware, i2c, pi-zero-w, gpiozero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W connected to a Adafruit T-Cobbler Plus and breadboard. My question is regarding wiring. I have followed tutorials to create simple circuits, however, I am struggling to understand the D6T sensor usage manual.

[image: The circuit I'd like to create]

I would love to know how to wire this specifically. I know there might not be a direct answer out there, so even resource for how to understand this diagram would be super helpful. Thank you!

As a note, I have already attempted the wiring using a few tutorials and am looking for fresh perspectives before diving back into this.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear just what you have done or are contemplating.

**DO NOT DO THIS ** connecting the Pi to 5V will damage it.